# Read S3 file based on the path that comes in Kafka - Apache Flink

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a pipeline that listens to a Kafka topic that receives the s3 file-name & path. The pipeline has to read the file from S3 and do some transformation & aggregation.
I see the Flink has support to read the S3 file directly as source connector, but this use case is to read as part of the transformation stage.

Comment: this is likely not possible out-of-the-box but could be achieved with custom source. you have to be careful about the watermark though

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible.

An alternative might be to keep a Flink session cluster running, and dynamically create and submit a new Flink SQL job running in batch mode to handle the ingestion of each file.

Another approach you might be tempted by would be to implement a RichFlatMapFunction that accepts the path as input, reads the file, and emits its records one by one. But this is likely to not work very well unless the files are rather small because Flink really doesn't like to have user functions that run for long periods of time.